# Output of different querisets in the Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Perhaps a little incorrectly formulated the question. In general, I do not understand how to transfer various collections of objects using DRF.  I need to list all the places, the list of the most popular and the list is the editor's choice. I'm trying to understand by analogy with django views.

```
def places_list(request):
    places = Places.objects.all()
    editor_places = Places.objects.filter(editor_choice = True )
    popular_places = Places.objects.filter(most_popular = True )

    return render (request, "places/places_list.html",
                   {"places": places,
                    "editor_places": editor_places,
                    "popular_places": popular_places,
                    })
```

And then in the template I display 3 tables with the parameters I need.

MAke API

**serializer.py**

```
class PlaeceSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
    view_name='places_api:detail',
    lookup_field='pk'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Places
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'main_photo',
            'name',           
        )
```

**views.py**

```
class PlacesListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Places.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlaeceSerializer
```

So I have a json collection that contains all the objects. How to make a sample correctly? In views.py or can it be like working on the front with the data? Share your experience, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the `def list` from [ListAPIView](http://www.cdrf.co/3.7/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html#list). So you should customize you Response like:

```
  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    places = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    editor = self.get_serializer(Places.objects.filter(editor_choice = True ), many=True)
    popular = self.get_serializer(Places.objects.filter(most_popular = True ), many=True)
    return Response({'places': places.data,'editor': editor.data,'popular': popular.data})
```

Comment: A great way! I did a little differently, wrote a solution in the answer

Answer (score 0):

class MultiFilterPlacesListView(ListAPIView):
     """Custom queryset api view. Does not implement pagination"""

```
 pagination_class = None
 queryset = Places.objects.all()
 slice_size = 10 

 def get_queryset(self):
     """Combine queries from new, editor choice and popular"""
     new_qs = self.queryset.filter(new_place=True)[:self.slice_size]
     editor_qs = self.queryset.filter(editor_choice=True)[:self.slice_size]
     popular_qs = self.queryset.filter(popular=True)[:self.slice_size]

     return new_qs.union(editor_qs, popular_qs, all=True)
```